# jQuery plugin issue: focus not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, focus

This is the plugin:

```
(
function($)
{  
    $.fn.foo=function()
    {  
        $(this).focus()

        return $(this)
    }
}
)(jQuery)
```

Now, `$('input#foo').foo()` does not get focus. Any idea why?

Comment: I've also tried $(this).trigger('focus'). No-no as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function($){ 

    $.fn.foo= function(map){ 

        return this.each(function(){

           // element-specific code here
           $(this).focus();

        });

    };


})(jQuery);
```

more about [Plugin Authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).

Comment: if your codes is working without errors, that should do... look at this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SNmDg/)

Comment: ok, there must be an error somewhere. i was looking for if something was stealing the focus, but its not the case either. http://jsfiddle.net/LMfrp/

Comment: actually this line `if (!("autofocus" in document.createElement("input")))` was not true at all that's why the's no focus happening... [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LMfrp/2/)

Comment: well, which browser are you using? in firefox 3.6.8, it is true. In Chromium, which enables autofocus, it is not.

Comment: sorry, its just me being very stupid. I ask the element to get focus before I append it to the DOM in my code, hence err of course. Thanks anyway Reigel!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your foo function expects a parameter:

```
$('input#foo').foo("mymap");
```

Comment: sorry, i'll remove the parameter. I'm just presenting a minimized view of the function

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this)[0].focus();`

`$().focus()` fires the events bound to `focus` for a particular element. `$()[0].focus()` calls focus on the DOM element itself, which causes the browser focus to change.